# ImageMagick Mac OS Eclipse Linker Issue

Tags: eclipse, imagemagick, osx-lion, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use ImageMagick 6.7.3 with a C++ project in eclipse on my mac air running osx lion. I have been fighting with it for a few days googling and researching I can't seem to get the linker to find the files no matter what I try. Here is my linker log from eclipse does anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

I have populated the library search path and the include path settings in properties -> c/c++ build -> settings menus with the paths to the ImageMagick installation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Build of configuration Debug for project ImportingLibrary **

make all 
Building target: ImportingLibrary
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L/Users/jon/Programs/ImageMagick-6.7.3/lib -o "ImportingLibrary"  ./src/ChoicePath.o ./src/ImageCreation.o ./src/NavFocus.o ./src/RouteInputAnalyzer.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MagickWandGenesis", referenced from:
      _main in NavFocus.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ImportingLibrary] Error 1

Build Finished **

Build of configuration Release for project ImportingLibrary **

make all 
Building file: ../src/NavFocus.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/NavFocus.d" -MT"src/NavFocus.d" -o "src/NavFocus.o" "../src/NavFocus.cpp"
../src/NavFocus.cpp:13:29: warning: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
../src/NavFocus.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../src/NavFocus.cpp:19: error: 'MagickWandGenesis' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [src/NavFocus.o] Error 1

Build Finished **